# suppress superclass method is not working in PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit4, powermockito

I want to suppress `Users` class `insertUser` method by `PowerMockito.suppress` method. But it seems that suppress method is not working well. i.e. it is calling method anyway. 
I tried to use `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Users.class, "insertUser", users);` instead, but I got NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:67)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:42)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:105)
    at test.UsersImplTest.insertUser(UsersImplTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
```

I know that it is not good idea to call `super.insertUser(users);`, and I know that it is not good design to call it. But I wonder why `suppress` method is not working. You can see codes below.

User.class

```
package test;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Super class

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Users {

    private Connection connection;

    public Users(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public abstract int getId();
    public abstract User getUser();
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract void setName(String name);

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void insertUser(List<User> users) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Extending superclass

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.List;

public class UsersImpl extends Users {

    public UsersImpl(Connection connection) {
        super(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
    }

    private void validate(List<User> users) {
        for (User user : users) {
            if (isExists(user)) {
                users.remove(user);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isExists(User user) {
        return false;
    }

    public void insertUser(List<User> users) {
        validate(users);
        super.insertUser(users);
    }
}
```

Here I am validating data before insertion. i.e. checking if user already exists. and after that I am inserting user into the database. Here is a test I ran:

```
package test;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({UsersImpl.class, Users.class})
public class UsersImplTest {

    private Connection connection;
    private UsersImpl usersImpl;
    private List<User> users;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        connection = PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);
        PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.constructor(UsersImpl.class));
        usersImpl = PowerMockito.spy(new UsersImpl(connection));
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("John"));
        users.add(new User("Smith"));
        users.add(new User("Caro"));
        users.add(new User("Debby"));
    }

    @Test
    public void insertUser() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.method(Users.class, "insertUser", List.class));
        PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(usersImpl, "isExists", new User("Smith"));

        usersImpl.insertUser(users);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested your code and it is suprressing the insertUser() method as intended, doesn't it for you? Which mockito dependencies are you using?

Comment: @luc14n0 I am using maven dependencies powermock-api-mockito-junit4-1.6.4 and powermock-module-junit4-1.5.

Comment: Try using version 1.6.5 for both. Version 1.6.4 isn't supressing the method for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you mentioned you were using powermock version 1.6.4 dependencies. I've tested the code with both 1.6.4 and 1.6.5 and it only supressed the insertUser() method when using 1.6.5:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I've found a related bug issue for version 1.6.3:

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/590

The bug occurs when trying to supress a spy's method.